# Cloud9 Node js Express jade IDE: file structure

Tags: node.js, express, pug, cloud9-ide

In Cloud9 Express IDE example I see in folder/file routes/users.js - please tell me why this is in separate file -what is the intention of users.js as a distinct file? :

```
/*

    GET users listing.
    */

exports.list = function(req, res){
res.send("respond with a resource");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

ok Im trying to answer that one myself (feel free to chime in): 
The basic Express set up folder  structure according to Expressjs.com looks like this:

├── app.js

├── bin

│   └── www

├── package.json

├── public

│   ├── images

│   ├── javascripts

│   └── stylesheets

│       └── style.css

├── routes

│   ├── index.js

│   └── users.js

└── views

```
├── error.jade

├── index.jade

└── layout.jade
```

It is suggested and not obligatory. However for noobs like me this [helpful website](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1858263&seqNum=4) says:

> *If you are getting started with Express it is recommended that you use the structure from the generator.*

Edited:
In the particular folder structure generated in Cloud9 Express the file /routes/users IS intrinsic to a typical Express-Jade setup. 
Basic routing tutorial [here](http://expressjs.com/starter/basic-routing.html) answers what each of these files is doing